# data-add-back-btn="true" not adding a back button

Tags: jquery-mobile

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/WmrUP/), but when I do this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>My header</h1>
</div>
<div class="ui-content">
    My content
</div>
```

I don't get a back button.

Comment: Add another page, it won't show on one page in dom ;)

Comment: [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/WmrUP/1/) Thanks Omar!